# How can a cell have 2 formula conditions in Google Sheets/Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to filter "confirmed" users.

I have a column (`DATA!A`) where all user names are found, those who confirmed their status are colored in green.

There's another column (`DATA!B`) where the specific status of the users can be found.

So I have 2 separated functions, one counts confirmed users: `COUNTA(valuesByColor("#00ff00", "#000000", Data!A3:A260)`

And the other one counts specific status, for example: `COUNTIF(Data!B3:B200, "TOP")`

Now what I want is a formula that for example counts all `"TOP"` cells in (`B`) that are confirmed, which means count only if their respective (`A`) is green.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: try a `COUNTIFS` formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Google Sheets, you can't count by background color without addon or script and even with those, you won't be able to combine those two formulae mostly because the majority of scripts just counts it as total, not per row. the easiest solution would be to give up on counting background color and have a helper column. then you could just use `FILTER` or `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: Ended up doing this, I had to manually copy about 100 cells but it's doing what I wanted I guess.

Sucks that I can't just count by background color.